# Unable to fetch correct row in codeigniter by using multiple join

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to multiple like condition in bracket.
Here is my `CI Active Record` code:-

```
$this->db->select("ev.`created_date`,u.first_name,u.last_name,ev.`expert_id` , ev.`posted_by` ,
        ev.`segment_id` , ev.`expert_title` , ev.`expert_discription` , ev.`status` , s.segment", FALSE);
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'expert_view as ev');
    $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'segment as s', 's.segment_id=ev.segment_id');
    $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'users as u', 'u.id=ev.posted_by');
    if ($this->session->userdata('group_id') != 1) {
        $this->db->where('ev.posted_by', $this->session->userdata('userid'));
    }
    if ($sSearch) {
        $this->db->like('u.first_name', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('u.last_name', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('ev.created_date', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('ev.posted_by', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('ev.`expert_title`', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('s.`segment`', $sSearch);
    }
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

**Output come from above code:**

```
SELECT ev.`created_date`, u.first_name, u.last_name, ev.`expert_id`, ev.`posted_by`, ev.`segment_id`
, ev.`expert_title`, ev.`expert_discription`, ev.`status`, s.segment
FROM (`adv_expert_view` as ev)
JOIN `adv_segment` as s ON `s`.`segment_id`=`ev`.`segment_id`
JOIN `adv_users` as u ON `u`.`id`=`ev`.`posted_by`
WHERE `ev`.`posted_by` =  '14'
AND  `u`.`first_name`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `u`.`last_name`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `ev`.`created_date`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `ev`.`expert_title`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `s`.`segment`  LIKE '%a%'
```

**Expected query:**

```
 SELECT ev.`created_date`, u.first_name, u.last_name, ev.`expert_id`, ev.`posted_by`, ev.`segment_id`
, ev.`expert_title`, ev.`expert_discription`, ev.`status`, s.segment
FROM (`adv_expert_view` as ev)
JOIN `adv_segment` as s ON `s`.`segment_id`=`ev`.`segment_id`
JOIN `adv_users` as u ON `u`.`id`=`ev`.`posted_by`
WHERE `ev`.`posted_by` =  '14'
AND  (`u`.`first_name`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `u`.`last_name`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `ev`.`created_date`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `ev`.`expert_title`  LIKE '%a%'
OR  `s`.`segment`  LIKE '%a%')
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using CI 3 You can use `->group_start()` and `->group_end()` for adding bracket. For more detail read [Query grouping](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

```
$this->db->group_start()
$this->db->like('u.first_name', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('u.last_name', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('ev.created_date', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('ev.posted_by', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('ev.`expert_title`', $sSearch);
        $this->db->or_like('s.`segment`', $sSearch);

$this->db->group_end()
```

FOR CI 2 You can create your condition as

```
$this->db->where("(`u`.`first_name` LIKE '%a%' OR `u`.`last_name` LIKE '%a%' OR `ev`.`created_date`  LIKE '%a%' OR  `ev`.`expert_title`  LIKE '%a%' OR `s`.`segment`  LIKE '%a%')");
```

Comment: i'm using CI 2.1 and it show error `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::group_start()`

Comment: @chotesah this function only for CI 3 not for CI 2.

Comment: then what is the solution? @Saty

Comment: Thanks @Saty for quick reply as answer and comments.

Comment: Hi @clsah if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:-

```
$query = "SELECT ev.`created_date`, u.first_name, u.last_name, ev.`expert_id`, ev.`posted_by`, ev.`segment_id`
, ev.`expert_title`, ev.`expert_discription`, ev.`status`, s.segment
FROM (`adv_expert_view` as ev)
JOIN `adv_segment` as s ON `s`.`segment_id`=`ev`.`segment_id`
JOIN `adv_users` as u ON `u`.`id`=`ev`.`posted_by`";

        $query.= " WHERE";

        if ($this->session->userdata('group_id') != 1) {
            $query.= " `ev`.`posted_by` =" . $this->session->userdata('userid') . " AND";
        }

        if ($sSearch) {
            $query.= " (`u`.`first_name`  LIKE '%$sSearch%'
                OR  `u`.`last_name`  LIKE '%$sSearch%'
                OR  `ev`.`created_date`  LIKE '%$sSearch%'
                OR  `ev`.`expert_title`  LIKE '%$sSearch%'
                OR  `s`.`segment`  LIKE '%$sSearch%')";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$this->db->where("(`u`.`first_name`LIKE '%a%'OR `u`.`last_name` LIKE '%a%' OR `ev`.`created_date`  LIKE '%a%' OR  `ev`.`expert_title`  LIKE '%a%' OR `s`.`segment`  LIKE '%a%')");
```